# What is the equivalent of Vue.prototype in angular?

Tags: angular, vue.js, singleton

I've working with Vue.js since a year ago, and now I've to start working with Angular, I got used to share an object instance between all component with Vue.prototype, so I didn't need to call it in every component.

eg. calling this.$toast.

I don't know if there is something similar in Angular.

I'm Using Angular 8.

I read the guide about singleton services but it keeps passing the instance to the constructor of the component I need it
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.prototype` can be modified in Vue to provide global dependencies and change the behaviour of all application components. There is no counterpart in Angular, the concept of application-wide dependencies was discarded since AngularJS.

The disadvantage of `Vue.prototype` modification is the same as the advantage, it provides global scope for the application and changes the behaviour of the entire application. In case the behaviour is undesirable, it cannot be easily decoupled from the application. This prevents parts of the application to be easily extracted and reused. Since third-party extensions are free to modify `Vue.prototype`, modifications can clash in unexpected ways, e.g. `$toast` name can be used by two different extensions/plugins.

On the other hand, Angular requires some boilerplate code that results in better application architecture. It heavily makes use of dependency injection, commonly used singleton can be accessed by injecting toast service:

```
class Component {
  constructor(public toast: Toast) {}
}
```

There can be base component class that results in DRYer components. Usually the amount of dependencies that requires to use base class means that there's something wrong with class design.

It's possible to discard dependency injection and rely on ES modules for a singleton, this results in less boilerplate but more shortcomings, e.g. testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not femiller `Vue.prototype` but can create a singleton object shared between all component with services that add to providers list to app.module level

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root" // 
})
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

> not in you don't use providedIn you can manually add the service tio
>   app.module

```
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [SharedService] // 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the service will be created once and inject as the same instant everytime you injected to any component

Comment: Can you show me an implementation of that in a component? I mean, I want to avoid passing the service to the component constructor, just typing this.sharedService in any part, without constructor. That´s how Vue.prototype works.

Comment: The idea here as i said is created a global service you can create a refrend to the service and used as it just an object and you have a reference to that object or you can manualy inject the service I will update ny anwer if the what you want

Comment: check this example where I create a global service and save a refrence to that service this help me to use the service without injected to the constructor everytine not this will work in singleton  service (global) check a,c and app.component ts files